# Service Management Request Tracker in WASABi (Windows Azure Autoscaling Application Block)

Tags: azure

What is the purpose of "Service Management Request Tracker"? Can me someone show some useful sample, how and when to use it?

Answer (score 0):

most of the scaling operations/requests are done async. you use the request tracker to log and check success/failure of these requests.